# Firebase Auth Token validation with Spring Security for REST API

Tags: spring, firebase, rest, authentication, spring-security

I am planning to use Firebase for auth purpose for my Application. The app has a java based back-end using Spring Boot. My understanding so far is that Firebase will handle different type of login options interacting directly with my front-end code and in return will give a token after user has logged in(primarily email based,Google or FB login). I have a few questions:

1. Does it provide a JWT type token that can be used in conjunction with my back-end without having to talk to Firebase servers from my back-end? I guess its not and SDK provides ways to validate token
2. Is there a good example of configuring my spring security to validate the the token and get user details? 
   I could not find a working example with Admin SDK of firebase using spring security.
3. What other tech stack options I have? I read Amazon Cognito could be one. My app is more of a POC and don't want to host my auth server as well.
4. What the recommendation on storing the user info in my own back-end or should I just rely on firebase servers to handle my user base?

Pardon my primitive understanding of Auth frameworks!

Comment: any progress in this issue?

Comment: There is a couple articles in the web to start. For example: https://medium.com/@purikunal22/securing-springboot-api-using-firebase-authentication-16d72dd250cc